# How to test promises with HttpTestingController?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

In an angular 2 application, I have a data service that converts the http observables to promises, in order to use the async/await sweetness, something like this:

```
async getCustomer(id: number): Promise<Customer> {
   return await this._http.get<Customer>(`${this.serverUrl}/customer/${id}`).toPromise();
}
```

This is operational and looks and works great.

My previous unit tests used the `MockBackend` with something like

```
mockBackend.connections.subscribe(c => {
   expect(c.request.url).toBe(`${serverUrl}/customer/${id}`);
   let response = new ResponseOptions({ body: mockResponseBody });
   expect(c.request.method).toBe(RequestMethod.Get);
   c.mockRespond(new Response(response));
});

let actual = await service.getCustomer(id);
```

However, now when I try something like this with

```
httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
// ... 1
let actual = await service.getCustomer(id);
// ... 2
```

I'm getting in a chicken-and-egg situation. The `getCustomer` method will not return until a mocked request is provided, and I cannot use `httpMock.expectOne` or `httpMock.match` until the http call is triggered.
So if I put a `httpMock` call in [1], I'm getting an expectation fail, and if I put it in [2], I'm getting a timeout error :(

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how `TestBed` exactly works. I don't see why does it prevent you from installing a mock before the `getCustomer` call is made. You should use a framework that lets you do so.

But it is possible to do with the current setup: just postpone awaiting on the promise!

```
httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
let customerPromise = service.getCustomer(id);
let request = httpMock.expectOne('http://myurl.com'); 
let actual = await customerPromise;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was stupid of me. Kinda forgot that the promise is a value onto itself :)

Comment: the mockResponsd() is req.flush({}),   const req = httpMock .expectOne(). and put await at last:

Comment: Does not work for me. Even if I don't wait for the promise before calling `expectOne()`, it is still being called too early before the actual request hits the test controller.

Comment: When do you check for the mock result? When do you flush?